# Runtime Complexity of Recursive Sequence

Tags: computational-complexity

I am given $T(n)=2T(n-1)+5^n$, and asked to find the runtime complexity. If there were no $5^n$ term, then the $T(n)$ would clearly be linear, $O(n)$. However, does the $5^n$ term make the complexity of this function $O(5^n)$?

Comment: It would not be linear without that term it would be exponential - $O(2^n)$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Why would it be exponential? Would it not just do 1 operation $n$ times until the base case was reached?

Comment: Well I assumed that if $T(n)=2^n$ that would imply $O(T(n))=O(2^n)$ but you meant the number of operations performed which is completely different.